# $location.path('url') not work

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i have been trying to redirect my application to the following link using 
$location.path('/main/details');

[image: see my _layout cshtml page]

The current url when I click the button is /main and I would like it to be changed to 
/main/details 
this url is called when I clicked on the button "details"  within main.cshtml and the page details will be shown if
i remove the attribute ng-controller(ng-controller="SettingsCtrl") the page will be shown

Comment: where is the relevant javascript code? Your question to me is a bit confusing. Do you mean to have a details link on the _layout cshtml page? I don't see a details link there.

Comment: i have home link on the _layout that redirect me to he home page after that i click on details link (by clicking a function will be called that allows me to show the details page)

Comment: I think we would need to see both the javascript code (wherever you have the line `$location.path('/main/details');`) and the home page markup then.

Comment: MainController :  $scope.details = function () {
        viewModelHelper.navigateTo('MainItem/Details');
    }

Comment: and the viewmoelHelper :      self.navigateTo = function (path, params) {
            if (params == null)
                $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path);
            else
                $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path).search(params);
        }

Comment: it works only when i removed the settings controller from _layout.cshtml

Comment: you can edit your question with this code (and more code around it). It is very hard to get a grasp when it is disjointed in the comments like this.

Comment: see this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/C4aU1.png

Comment: that's a lot better. You should really paste this code as a code block in your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply bro i can't post another code block until 90minutes so can u help ?

Comment: when you say you want it to be changed to `/main/details` do you mean the `MainItem/Details` which it seems to be doing in your code?

Can you put `console.log` commands in the `if (params == null)` block and log `$location`, `path`, `MyApp.rootPath` and `params`?

Also looks like you have a capital S in self and then a lowercase?

Comment: yes i meant MainItem/Details capital S fixed but the problem still there and i used console.log and it shows the message but the redirection still not working

Comment: okay what did the console print exactly?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4MVNU.png

Comment: did you do a separate console log for each of the things i mentioned? What is being logged there?

Comment: this log is when i click on details button to go from MainItem/ to MainItem/Details

Comment: can you put a `console.log($location); console.log(path); console.log(MyApp.rootPath); console.log(params);` inside the `if (params == null)` block and show me the results?